# Write dataframe on excel if excel is already opened

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
df = pd.read_excel(r'path\file.xlsx')
df.dropna()

writer = ExcelWriter(r'path\file.xlsx)
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

The problem is this: if actually I have the xlsx.file already opened, I receive an error message like: permission denied.

How can I write into an excel already opened, without saving it and closing it?

Answer (score 0):

Python will not overwrite a file that is in use.  If you have no control whether or not the file is open when you want to write anyway, consider using a different name, trying again later, or using psutil to kill excel thus releasing the lock and trying again.